# Proving subsets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Let $a,b,c,n$ be non-zero integers.

Let $S$ be the set of integer solutions to $ax+by=nc$ and

$T$={$(nx,ny):(x,y)$ is an integer solution to $ax+by=c$}.

I need to prove/disprove that $S \subseteq T, T \subseteq S, S=T$.

I am thinking $S \subsetneq T$ because there are some integer solutions  $(x,y)$ such that $(x,y) \in S$ but $(x,y) \notin T$. So then I would need to prove $T \subseteq S.$

Does anyone know how I can go about solving this...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be careful with your notation: $S \subsetneq T$ means $S \subseteq T$ and $S\not=T$. I think you meant to say that $S\not\subseteq T$.

Comment: To prove that $T\subseteq S$, take an element of $T$ and show that it is also an element of $S$. I don't think you can prove that $S\not=T$ unless you have more information about $a,b,c,n$; certainly $S=T$ if $n=1 \ldots$

Comment: I edited in the word "solution" in your def'n of T.

Answer (score 1):

$T\subset S$ because $(n x, n y)\in T\implies a (n x)+b (n y)=n(a x+b y)=n c\implies (n x, n y)\in S.$

For an example where $T\ne S,$ let $a=b=n=2$ and $c=1.$ Then $T$ is empty but $(1,0)\in S.$

For an example where $T=S,$ let $n=1.$

For an example where $\phi \ne T\ne S, $ let $a=3, b=5, c=1,n=2. $  Then  $(9,-5)\in S$ and $(9,-5)\not \in T$ but $(2,-1)\in T.$

More generally : Let $e=\gcd (a,b)$.If $T\ne  \phi $ then $e|c$ because any $a x+b y$ is divisible by $e.$

Suppose $e|c$ and $|n|>1$. There are integers $x_0, y_0$ with $a x_0+b y_0=e.$  Then $a(n  x_0 (c/e)+ b/e)+b( n y_0 (c/e)-a/e)=(n c/e)(a x_0+b y_0)+(a b/e-b a/e)=(n c/e)e=n c.$

Observe  that $n x_0 (c/e)$ and $n y_0 (c/e)$ are integers because $e|c$, and that  $b/e,\; a/e$ are integers by def'n of $e.$

So $(n x_0 (c/e)+b/e, n y_0 (c/e)-a/e)$ belongs to  $S.$  But it does not belong to  $T$ because otherwise $n|(b/e)$ and $n|(a/e),$ which is impossible. ( Because $|n|>1$ and  $\gcd (a/e,b/e)=\gcd (a/\gcd (a,b), b/\gcd (a,b) )=1.$)